# Foreach loop only returns first index on multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array within an array within an array that looks like this:

```
$flattened_pics = array (
    [0] = array (
        _A = array (a bunch of data),
        _B = array (a bunch of data)
    ),
    [1] = array (
        _A = array (a bunch of data),
        _B = array (a bunch of data)
    )
)
```

When I run the following function on the outer array, it successfully returns results on the inner array for index [0], but not index [1].

```
$goods['arts'] = Goods_Model_Ajax::convertLettered_arrays($flattened_pics);
```

I need it to return results for both $flattened_pics[0] and $flattened_pics[1].

I have tried single foreach loops (like below), nested foreach loops, and other variations. Perhaps I need to put an index in this but I'm not sure.

```
    if($flattened_pics) {
        foreach($flattened_pics AS $goods) {
            $goods['pics'] = array(Goods_Model_Ajax::convertLettered_arrays($goods)
            );

        }
    }
```

Here is what the function convertLettered_arrays looks like.

```
public static function convertLettered_arrays($pics)
{
    $out_pictures = array();
    $out_pictures['picture_a'] = array();
    $out_pictures['picture_b'] = array();
    $out_pictures['picture_c'] = array();
    $out_pictures['picture_d'] = array();

    $out_pictures['picture_a']['image'] = $pics[0]['_A']['picture_temp.image'];
    $out_pictures['picture_a']['original'] = $pics[0]['_A']['picture_temp.original'];
    $out_pictures['picture_a']['width'] = $pics[0]['_A']['picture_temp.width'];
    $out_pictures['picture_a']['height'] = $pics[0]['_A']['picture_temp.height'];
    $out_pictures['picture_a']['mime'] = $pics[0]['_A']['picture_temp.mime'];

    $out_pictures['picture_b']['image'] = $pics[0]['_B']['picture_temp.image'];
    $out_pictures['picture_b']['original'] = $pics[0]['_B']['picture_temp.original'];
    $out_pictures['picture_b']['width'] = $pics[0]['_B']['picture_temp.width'];
    $out_pictures['picture_b']['height'] = $pics[0]['_B']['picture_temp.height'];
    $out_pictures['picture_b']['mime'] = $pics[0]['_B']['picture_temp.mime'];

    $out_pictures['picture_c']['image'] = $pics[0]['_C']['picture_temp.image'];
    $out_pictures['picture_c']['original'] = $pics[0]['_C']['picture_temp.original'];
    $out_pictures['picture_c']['width'] = $pics[0]['_C']['picture_temp.width'];
    $out_pictures['picture_c']['height'] = $pics[0]['_C']['picture_temp.height'];
    $out_pictures['picture_c']['mime'] = $pics[0]['_C']['picture_temp.mime'];

    $out_pictures['picture_d']['image'] = $pics[0]['_D']['picture_temp.image'];
    $out_pictures['picture_d']['original'] = $pics[0]['_D']['picture_temp.original'];
    $out_pictures['picture_d']['width'] = $pics[0]['_D']['picture_temp.width'];
    $out_pictures['picture_d']['height'] = $pics[0]['_D']['picture_temp.height'];
    $out_pictures['picture_d']['mime'] = $pics[0]['_D']['picture_temp.mime'];

    return $out_pictures;
}
```

Comment: I suppose the problem is your function convertLettered_arrays(). We can't help without this function.

Comment: Tx @VincentDecaux, just added the function. It looks like the function is not iterating through the index????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should loop like this.

```
if ($flattened_pics) {
    foreach ($flattened_pics AS $goods) {
        $converted[] = Goods_Model_Ajax::convertLettered_arrays($goods);
    }
}
```

Then in your `convertLettered_arrays` function, you just remove all the `[0]`. Something like this:

```
$out_pictures['picture_a']['image'] = $pics['_A']['picture_temp.image'];
$out_pictures['picture_a']['original'] = $pics['_A']['picture_temp.original'];
$out_pictures['picture_a']['width'] = $pics['_A']['picture_temp.width'];
$out_pictures['picture_a']['height'] = $pics['_A']['picture_temp.height'];
$out_pictures['picture_a']['mime'] = $pics['_A']['picture_temp.mime'];
```

You can check the output by dumping converted array

`var_dump($converted)`;

I also suggest just looping on your `convertLettered_arrays` function so you can avoid having thick codes

Comment: Thanks very much, @Erwin. That worked perfectly.  I am not very good at arrays and looping yet, otherwise, I'd def condense this.

Comment: @ian, welcome. Of course, we all start slowly learning each things. Goodluck on your projects! :)